# how to call rows in sql with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am not new to the nodejs or sql coding just very new to the sql with nodejs

here is my code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "cFeu11qJgQ8lNxhO",
  database: "users"
});
```

message is the variable that the chat message is set to

```
 con.query("SELECT * FROM chatmessages WHERE InComingChat=", message, function (err,rows) {
            rows.forEach( (row) => {
            console.log("",row.InComingChat," is in ",row.OutComingChat);
            });
})
```

but it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined  how should it be written  to get the values in InComingChat and output the value in OutComingChat?

Answer (score 0):

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM chatmessages WHERE InComingChat=", message, function (err,rows) {
            rows.forEach( (row) => {
            console.log("",row.InComingChat," is in ",row.OutComingChat);
            });
})
```

> Here `rows` is an array with one element for every statement in the query:

try this

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM chatmessages WHERE InComingChat=", message, function (err,rows) {
            rows[0].forEach( (row) => {
            console.log("",row.InComingChat," is in ",row.OutComingChat);
            });
})
```

[read this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows) - Based on querying this is the structure they have defined.

```
connection.query('SELECT 1; SELECT 2', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // `results` is an array with one element for every statement in the query:
  console.log(results[0]); // [{1: 1}]
  console.log(results[1]); // [{2: 2}]
});
```